# How to Send Hex string from uart to microcontroller and store it to integer for future "if" statement

Tags: c, avr

okay, im really beg for a help here, cause im hittin a rock bottom. ive spend weeks to do this and still not able to.

i have an avr, i will recive a string containing hex value in it from UART.

ex :

```
0x3cffaa31
```

i need to split it into

```
0x3c
0xff
0xaa
0x31
```

and store it into a variable so i can do if statement with it.

how can i achieve this, please help me. i already lookin here and there on the internet yet i still lost.

Answer (score 0):

Help me out if I'm interpreting this wrong, but it sounds like you need to;

1. split the incoming string from the UART into indidual 2-character   strings, each one representing a byte of hex. If you will always have 4 bytes of data, in the format that you've shown, then this will be easy. e.g. you always know that the two characters of the first byte are at index 2 and 3 of the `char[]` holding your input string.
2. Convert each two-character string to an int, so you can use them for numerical calculations. Look at `strtol`, which is available in AVR libc, for this http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/AVRLibcReferenceManual/group__avr__stdlib_1gaf8ce3b8dae3d45c34c3b172de503f7b3.html 
   Make sure to specify base16 for `strtol`-- e.g.:

   ```
   long converted = strtol(digits, NULL, 16);
   ```

(where `digits` is a `char[]` containing your two hex characters, null-terminated)

UPDATE- looks like `strtol` doesn't care if the string has a preceding `0x`, so something like this would work to get the first hex value from the raw string:

```
    const char *raw = "0x3cffaa31";
    char digits[3];
    long converted;

    /* Copy two bytes from 'raw', starting from index 2,
     * (so we can skip the '0x') to get the string "3c" */
    strncpy(digits, raw + 2, 2);

    /* Make sure the new string is null-terminated */
    digits[2] = '\0';

    /* Convert hex string to a long. Now you can use it
     * in an if-statement */
    converted = strtol(digits, NULL, 16);
```

Comment: thx sir for your help, but.. is there any chance you have some example code for me to learn?

Comment: There *is* some sample code in my answer. I've done 25% of it, you just have to figure out how to do the same operations on the remaining portion of the string. I'll update it with comments so it's a bit clearer, but that's the best I can do.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint8_t Values[4]={0};
uint8_t Loc=0;
uint32_t Mask=0xFF; //32 bits UART Rx Buffer size

for(uint8_t i=0;i<=24;i+=8)
{
 Values[Loc]=(((Mask<<i) & UartRxBuf) >> i);
 Loc++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I donot think this is an issue 
If you are using uart in 8bit mode you will recieve only one byte data at a time .
Just increase the array index every time you recieve the data

```
for(i = 0; i<4; i++){
while(UART_recieve_not_completed);
arr[i] = UART_RX_BUFF;}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: its me that really a newby to c world. i mean, an example code would be really appreciated, the code you write above its still confusing for me as i dont know how and where to apply it